# Offline caching with Intel app framework?

Tags: html, caching, intel, intel-xdk, appframework

I'm starting an uphill journey developing a small app for my wife's speech pathology practice.  We want to publish an app that contains several html5 based games that promote language development.  Currently I'm looking at the intel app framework and xdk to do this.  We plan to start with a simple game (building words for example) then adding more games over time.

My question is this, html 5 has a cache mechanism using a manifest.  If I limit the games to a single page, can I store the games on a web server rather than forcing the user to download all of the content with the app at the time of install?  The objective here is to allow games to be added without forcing updates of the app.  I anticipate several Mb of sound clips and images per game.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML5 Application Caching in remote website and load it in the app using [Cordova InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser), so that when you click on a game, it opens a InAppBrowser and loads the game from webserver, this game can have the manifest with application cache, so that all content is downloaded on the device and launched.

You can develop the main app using [Intel AppFramework](http://app-framework-software.intel.com) and load the list of games via a REST API from web server, clicking on game can open a InAppBrowser and load the Application Cached game webpage from web server. This can all be done in [Intel XDK](http://xdk.intel.com)

Details on Application Cache can be found [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. When the user opens a game for the first time, it will require a network connection, correct? Also, after they load the game for the first time, will the InAppBrower keep the content cached according to the html5 manifest/caching feature indefinitely?

Comment: Yes, I did some test, it did work, not sure about indefinitely, you will have to try.

Comment: if you don't mind, just one more question... If I spawn the Cordova InAppBrowser, can I still make use of the Intel AppFramework or another framework (jquery maybe) in the game? That should work, right, as long as the game html refers to the framework on the web server. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes appframework is independent of XDK, it will work on inappbrowswer from webserver